# Get specific data row in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, code-behind

How do I get the specific data row of my GridView in asp.net?

I have this image here:

[image]

Example:
I want to get the specific data row of the studentID = 2011017997 and its CourseNo = 'CmpE 515';

how do I get their specific data? Does GridViewRow has one of that built in functions to get the data row?

Here is the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ValidateSubjectTeacher.aspx.cs" Inherits="SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD.ValidateSubjectTeacher" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Student Assessment Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/ValidateSubjectTeacherStyle.css"/>

    <!--Side bar link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SidebarBootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SidebarBootstrap/css/simple-sidebar.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <br />
        <h1>Validation of Subjects</h1>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" ID="ValidateSubject" Style="text-align: center"></asp:GridView>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; padding-right: 75px;">
        <button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="ValidateSubject_Click">Validate</button>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my aspx code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class ValidateSubjectTeacher : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["ValidateSubject"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("TeacherPage.aspx", true);
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ValidateSubject.DataSource = Session["ValidateSubject"];
                ValidateSubject.DataBind();
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in ValidateSubject.Rows)
            {
                check = row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as CheckBox; //position Check column on last row in gridview
                check.Enabled = true;
                check.CheckedChanged += ValidateSubject_Click; //Bind the event on the button
                check.AutoPostBack = true; //Set the AutoPostBack property to true
            }
        }
        protected void ValidateSubject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow grvRow = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;//This will give row

            string validated = "Validated";
            string notyetvalidated = "Not yet validated";

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                grvRow.Cells[10].Text = validated;
                //Open Connection
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    //Open Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AssessmentForm set Status = '@Validated' where StudentID = @studentID and CourseNo = '@Coursenumber'" ,conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Validated", validated);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", );
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coursenumber", );
                    }

                    //Close Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                grvRow.Cells[10].Text = notyetvalidated;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fetch the value of the studentID and courseNo in my gridview? I want to get the data row of Student ID and CourseNo and put it in one of my parameters here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coursenumber", );
```

This question is just a follow up question to this link here [(Change text in specific row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828799/change-text-in-specific-row-in-gridview-using-checkbox)
Now this time I want to update my query when checkbox event is checked and button ValidateSubject_Click event is fired.

Comment: Why do you need the `GridViewRow`? Normally you use the datasource(f.e. a database) if you need to find another record/row. Your approach would at least fail if you enable paging and the row is in a currently not existing page.

Comment: You have an issue with your parameters. You don't wrap them in apostrophes. Instead write it in this way: `Update AssessmentForm set Status = @Validated where StudentID = @studentID and CourseNo = @Coursenumber`

Comment: I'll take note of that. Yeah, that's a great risk in my program when it comes to pagination, the thing is I already bind my datasource in the page_load. Is it possible to retrieve a data when the gridview is already bind?

Comment: Can you show the relevant asp code? Do you use templatefields or boundfields? Do you want the studentid and coursenumber from the current row or from another?

Comment: I've edited my question sir, about the sqlcommand is that a correct way to query using parameters? My GridView is autogeneratedcolumns so I get all the dataTables and bind them and I want the studentid and coursenumber of the current row only.

Comment: they are still wrapped in apostrophes. Look at what i've shown in my previous comment.

Comment: Could you provide an answer sir? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you were able to access the **GridViewRow** using **gvRow**, you can access StudentID and Coursenumber from row cells 1 and 2 as follows

```
var studentID = grvRow.Cells[0].Text;
var courseNumber = grvRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: I get an error ((Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'.))

Comment: Thank you, I did get the data though.

Answer (score 1):

An other example to resolve your problem is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="StudentDataSource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Serial" SortExpression="Serial" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verified" SortExpression="Verified">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Verified") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Verified") %>' 
                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkVerified_CheckedChanged" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hddSerial" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Serial") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="You have validate: N/a"></asp:Label>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="StudentDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="Get" TypeName="WebFormApp._32846281.Models.Student"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

in your code behind:

```
 protected void chkVerified_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow grvRow = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;

        HiddenField hf = grvRow.FindControl("hddSerial") as HiddenField;

        lblResult.Text = string.Format("You have validate:{0}", hf.Value);

    }
```

That resolve this problem: if you reorder colums, with first the method, you must change code behind

In my solution if you reorder columns the code behind is same.